# Соединения проекта в Firebase и приложения в Unity

Tags: python-3.x, firebase

Задача: объединить Firebase и приложения в Unity.

Насколько я понимаю, там, где должен быть код соединения написаны только комментарии. А что туду нужно вписать я не очень понимаю. Информации в официальных источниках я не нашел.

Вот часть кода, которая отвечает за соединение и создание связи с БД:

````
FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith
        (
        task => 
            {
                var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
                if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
                {
                    // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
                    // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
                    //   app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

                    // Set a flag here to indicate whether Firebase is ready to use by your app.
                }
                else
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                        "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
                    // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
                }
            }
        );```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переменная auth:

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
```

была объявлена, как поле, вне void Awake() {...}